# Is there a common standard for how GIS information is displayed?

Tags: geojson, well-known-text, ogc, standards

New to GIS programming so this might be a silly question.  Is there a standard way to store/transmit *how* a GIS feature is to be displayed?  So I can see there's loads of standard ways of storing tha actual GIS data, WKT, WKB, GeoJSON etc, but how should I store display information?
e.g. I've got a polygon, it has a line width, line colour, colour, transparency, etc. How should this information best be stored that's technology neutral and preferably that's well understood by different systems?

Comment: SLD is the standard for styling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [SLD](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=22364) (Styled Layer Descriptor), which I think is mainly used in OpenGIS environments. ArcGIS might have *some* support for it, but I have never pursued that option myself.

Comment: Great, thanks this is what I was looking for, what's the Symbology Encoding spec though?

Comment: If you read the SE spec you'll find "This document is together with the Styled Layer Descriptor Profile for the Web Map
Service Implementation Specification the direct follow-up of Styled Layer Descriptor
Implementation Specification 1.0.0."